# ListView in Fragment in ViewPager Only Showing New Values After Screen Orientation Changes Twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

In my app I have a ViewPager with four fragments one of which contains a ListView which I dynamically add too at certain points using an update method that recreates the adapter. When the fragment is first loaded it displays all items perfectly but when I do operations later on, which add views to a list which is used to create the Fragment's ListView's adapter, the new items are not shown (or removed). Does anybody know why this occurs.

The Fragment with the ListView:

```
public static class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment
{
    ListView list;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View lv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, null);
        ListView list = (ListView) lv.findViewById(R.id.favorite_list);
        SeparatedListAdapter mAdapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(getActivity(), favoriteList); 
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return list;
    }

    public static FavoritesFragment newInstance(String text)
    {
        FavoritesFragment f = new FavoritesFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

The update method:

```
public static void update() {
    favoriteList = new ArrayList<SeparatedListAdapter.Item>(); 
    sections = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListMultimap<String, JSONObject> listObjects = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset(con));
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("Locations");

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) 
          {
           JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
           if (favorites.contains(jo_inside.getString("Unique"))) 
           {
               listObjects.put(jo_inside.getString("Section"), jo_inside);
               if (!sections.contains(jo_inside.getString("Section"))) sections.add(jo_inside.getString("Section"));
           }
          }
        }
   catch (JSONException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

    for (String s : sections)
    {
        favoriteList.add(new SeparatedListAdapter.SectionItem(s));
        List<JSONObject> objectsInSection = listObjects.get(s);
        for (JSONObject j : objectsInSection)
        {
            try {
            favoriteList.add(new SeparatedListAdapter.EntryItem(j.getString("name");
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When page is changed to Fragment with ListView:

```
View vc = mPager.findViewWithTag("favorites");
                        if (vc != null) {
                            ListView lv = (ListView) vc.findViewById(R.id.favorite_list);
                            update();
                            lv.setAdapter(new SeparatedListAdapter(MainActivity.this, favoriteList));
                            }
```

Sorry for the long post but any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: `SeparatedListAdapter mAdapter` should be a field and not a local variable, initialized only if it's `null` and on update (add / remove) you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: it didn't work, I added
if (mAdapter != null) mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
at the end of update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried calling this:

have mAdapter be an instance variable instead of instantiating it in the onCreateView

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

EDIT:::

what if you did something like this?

```
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.addAll(favoriteList);
```

Comment: when should I call that?

Comment: what do you mean by `global variable`?

Comment: im guessing instance variable?

Comment: yes instance variable.  you would call that after you've added stuff to your favoriteList.

Comment: my problem is that I'm adding to the SharedPreference in another activity so when I go back I have to recreate favoriteList, how can I do it in this case?

Comment: Thank you so much :DDD I used that and found I wasn't updating my SharedPreference correctly and it worked